# Why DeepZoomTools.dll reference is not accepted in WindowsForms?

Tags: silverlight, windowsformshost

I cannot find a way to add the DeepZoomTools.dll to a WindowsForms application. The steps I followed are:

1) Create a new WindowsForm application

2) Add Reference to DeepZoomTools.dll found in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Expression\Deep Zoom Composer

3) Add using Microsoft.DeepZoomTools; in Form1.cs

4) Click on Build WindowsFormsApplication

5) I get the error: "The type or namespace name 'DeepZoomTools' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Thanks in advance for your help,

Luis Nambiar

Answer (score 1):

If somebody has the same issue the solution is shown below.

Go to Project Properties and change the "Target framework" value from ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".NET Framework 4".

Best regards,

Luis Nambiar

Answer (score 0):

DeepZoomTools.dll is a Silverlight DLL for use in Silverlight applications. Even if you could link to it properly the supporting infrastructure it would need, e.g. for rendering, is not there.

You could in theory embed a Silverlight DeepZoom app inside a browser control inside a WinForms app, but it sounds like you do not know Silverlight so that may take some effort to learn all the new bits.